# Timed out error while loading data from DataProc (Hive) to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

We are getting a timed out error while loading data from DataProc (Hive) to BigQuery.

**Error:**

> Exception occurred: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bigquery.googleapis.com', port=443)`: Read timed out. (read timeout=None)

Can someone help with this issue?

We tried reducing the parallel jobs, but it's still getting the same error. I upgraded Python packages and GCP-related packages, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the data you are trying to load is too large and is taking too long to load. You can try increasing the timeout limit or splitting your data into smaller chunks to load it more efficiently. You can also check if there are any network issues or if there are any other processes running that might be causing the issue.